# Map two arrays together to create an indexed array containing associative rows

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mapping, associative-array

Say, I have an array with months

```
$months = array('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'...'Dec');
```

And another, with days (say, for year 2010)

```
$mdays = array(31, 28, 31...31);
```

I want to merge/combine these two arrays, into an array like this:

```
$monthdetails[0] = ('month' => 'Jan', 'days' => 31)

$monthdetails[1] = ('month' => 'Feb', 'days' => 28)

...

$monthdetails[11] = ('month' => 'Dec', 'days' => 31)
```

I can loop through both the arrays and fill the `$monthdetails`. I want to know whether there are any functions/easier way for achieving the same result.

Thanks!
Raj

Answer (score 3):

Given that the order of both arrays is the same:

```
foreach ($months as $key => $value) {
  $monthdetails[$key] = array('month' => $value, 'days' => $mdays[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[array_combine](http://php.net/array_combine)

```
$monthdetails = array_combine($months, $mdays);


echo $monthdetails['Jan']; //31
```

This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but you should adapt your system to use this method.

Comment: I cannot use this, as printing the key names isn't easy. Also, I may have to have more than 2 arrays merged in my app. The foreach/for loop method looks the only option.
Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both arrays are the same size:

```
$count = count($months);
$monthdetails = array();
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
    $monthdetails[] = array('month' => $months[$i], 'days' => $mdays[$i]);
}
```

Edit: Like the other answers, `array_combine()` immediately came to mind but it doesn't do exactly what the question asked.

Edit 2: I would still recommend against using such a direct approach, since it doesn't deal with the possibility of leap years. Re-inventing the date-time wheel is usually not a good idea.

Comment: The month-days case was an example to illustrate my requirement, not the actual requirement. I am not re-inventing the good date system in php :-)
Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

```
function month_callback( $month, $day ){
    return array( 'month' => $month,
                  'day' => $day );
}

$months = array( 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar' );
$days = array( 31, 28, 31 );

$monthdetails = array_map( 'month_callback', $months, $days );

print_r( $monthdetails );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map the two equally-sized arrays together, nominate the preferred row keys in the callback signature, then simply call `get_defined_vars()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/isMaj))

```
$months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Dec'];
$mdays = [31, 28, 31, 31];

var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($month, $days) => get_defined_vars(),
        $months,
        $mdays
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'month' => 'Jan',
    'days' => 31,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'month' => 'Feb',
    'days' => 28,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'month' => 'Mar',
    'days' => 31,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'month' => 'Dec',
    'days' => 31,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you can live with an array structure like this:

```
Array
(
    [Jan] => 31
    [Feb] => 28
    [Mar] => 31
    ...
    [Dec] => 31
)
```

Then [array_combine()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) is your friend:

```
$monthdetails = array_combine($months, $mdays);
```

It probably would be the fastest way...

Answer (score -1):

I believe array_combine does what you want: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

It uses the first array for keys and the second for values.

Answer (score -1):

Combine two arrays with array_combine? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php