# Transpose data from multiple flat arrays and add second level associative keys before calling CodeIgniter's update_batch() method

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, transpose, batch-updates

I'm having a problem with restructuring some array data.

I'm working with bulk upload data(Update) to database. So I have 3 arrays like this:

```
Array ( [0] => aaa [1] => ccc [2] => eee [3] => ggg ) 
Array ( [0] => bbb [1] => ddd [2] => fff [3] => hhh ) 
Array ( [0] => 1662 [1] => 1663 [2] => 1664 [3] => 1665 )
```

I need to restructure the array to the order below.

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'aaa' ,
      'Info' => 'bbb' ,
      'id' => '1662'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'ccc' ,
      'Info' => 'ddd' ,
      'id' => '1663'
   ),
      array(
      'title' => 'eee' ,
      'Info' => 'fff' ,
      'id' => '1664'
   ),
      array(
      'title' => 'ggg' ,
      'Info' => 'hhh' ,
      'id' => '1665'
   )
);

$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data,'id');
```

How I can restructure the array?

> Note : array content will be keep change when various type is selected.

ex:

```
array(
      'title' => 'Any value' ,
      'Info' => 'Any value' ,
      'id' => 'Any Id'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php 
<?php

$a1 = array('aaa','ccc','eee','ggg');
$a2 = array('bbb','ddd','fff','hhh');
$a3 = array(1662,1663,1664,1665);

// Output
$output = array_map(function($a,$b,$c){ return array('title'=>$a,'Info'=>$b,'id'=>$c);},$a1,$a2,$a3)

print_r ( $output );

// Here add your update statement
// $this->db->update_batch('mytable', $output,'id');

?>
```

**Output**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => aaa
            [Info] => bbb
            [id] => 1662
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => ccc
            [Info] => ddd
            [id] => 1663
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => eee
            [Info] => fff
            [id] => 1664
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => ggg
            [Info] => hhh
            [id] => 1665
        )

)
```

Comment: if array `$a1 = array('aaa','ccc','eee','ggg','rrr','mmm','nnn');` then??

Answer (score 0):

Making iterated calls of `get_defined_vars()` offers succinct elegance.  Just name the column parameters as you wish associative second level keys to be.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9W5bA))

```
$a1 = ['aaa', 'ccc', 'eee', 'ggg'];
$a2 = ['bbb', 'ddd', 'fff', 'hhh'];
$a3 = [1662, 1663, 1664, 1665];

var_export(
    array_map(fn($title, $Info, $id) => get_defined_vars(), $a1, $a2, $a3)
);
```

Related:

- 2010 : [Map two arrays together to create an indexed array containing associative rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2878007/2943403)
- 2015 : [Merging two flat arrays by shared indexes to create rows in a 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31623556/2943403)
- 2017 : [Transpose 2d array's associative array elements containing indexed rows of differing counts and enforce custom default values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43713947/2943403)
- 2019 : [Merge column values from two arrays to form an indexed array of associative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56731194/2943403)
- 2020 : [Join two flat, indexed arrays (by index) to form an indexed array of associative rows with hardcoded keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64661791/2943403)

Beyond those, if you want to build the desired associative keys into the assembly of a merged input array, you'll be able to cleanly write a nested loop process which can be found at: [Transposing multidimensional arrays in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/797251/2943403)