# Merging two flat arrays by shared indexes to create rows in a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mapping, merging-data

So I have two arrays.

```
$user_ids = array('123','124','125');
$names = array('john','bob','susie');
```

Now, all of those arrays are matched up. Meaning that 123 is the user_id for john, 124 is the user_id for Bob, etc. (So both arrays have matching keys)

But I want to end up with a multidimensional array for each user with their user_id and name instead of having them seperate.

```
[
    ['user_id' => 123, 'name' => 'john'],
    ['user_id' => 124, 'name' => 'bob'],
    ['user_id' => 125, 'name' => 'susie'],
]
```

Comment: [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)  will give you an array with names indexed by user_ids. Depending on your use case you may find that more useful

Comment: Sure you don't mean associative instead of multi-dimensional?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) or [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) according to your demand

```
$user_ids = array('123','124','125');
$names = array('john','bob','susie');

$new_array = array_combine($user_ids, $names);
```

or

```
$new_array = array_map(function($name, $id){
    return array('id'=>$id, 'name'=>$name);}, $names, $user_ids
);
```

Comment: spell check `array_combile` to `array_combine` :)

Answer (score 0):

Synchronously iterating multiple indexed arrays with the same element count is ideally and concisely performed by `array_map()`.

To elegantly declare the associative keys in each row without repeating yourself (D.R.Y.), declare variables with the desired key name as the text after the `$`, then call `get_defined_vars()` in the callback.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/p4I9o))

```
$user_ids = ['123', '124', '125'];
$names = ['john', 'bob', 'susie'];

var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($user_id, $name) => get_defined_vars(),
        $user_ids,
        $names
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'user_id' => '123',
    'name' => 'john',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'user_id' => '124',
    'name' => 'bob',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'user_id' => '125',
    'name' => 'susie',
  ),
)
```

---

For anyone seeking a transposed data set as an indexed array of indexed elements, then simply write `null` as the callback parameter. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UU32V))

```
var_export(
    array_map(null, $user_ids, $names)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => '123',
    1 => 'john',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => '124',
    1 => 'bob',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => '125',
    1 => 'susie',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$multiarr = array("id" => $user_ids, "names" => $names);
```

Comment: You posted with the tag PHP so I assumed PHP, but your code wasn't clear what language.