# Transpose 2d array's associative array elements containing indexed rows of differing counts and enforce custom default values

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp-3.0, transpose, default-value

How can I convert input array

```
$input['id'] = [1,2,3,4];
$input['name'] = ['a' , 'b' , 'c'];
$input['alias'] = ['i' , 'ii' , 'iii' , 'iv' , 'v'];
$input['object'] = [$object1 , $object2];
```

to output array

```
$output[] = ['id'=>1 , 'name'=>'a' , 'alias'=>'i' , 'object'=>$object1];
$output[] = ['id'=>2 , 'name'=>'b' , 'alias'=>'ii' , 'object'=>$object2];
$output[] = ['id'=>3 , 'name'=>'c' , 'alias'=>'iii' , 'object'=>NULL];
$output[] = ['id'=>4 , 'name'=>'' , 'alias'=>'iv' , 'object'=>NULL];
$output[] = ['id'=>0 , 'name'=>'' , 'alias'=>'v' , 'object'=>NULL];
```

missed number = 0
missed string = ''
missed object = null

Comment: Have you looked at the [zip](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake\Collection\Collection::zip) function of the Collections library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a first answer, i would do the following :

`$output = array_map(null, $input['id'], $input['name'], $input['alias'], $input['object']);`

This will create an array from your arrays.

Counterpart of this solution is that it always return `null` if value is not set.

More info : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php#example-5583

---

**EDIT 03 May 2017**
If you need to add the keys to the output (id, name, alias, object), you could apply a function to each item in the stack to add them.
The following is a possible solution :

`array_walk($output, function(&$item, $key) {
    $item = array_combine(['id','name','alias', 'object'], array_values($item));
});`

Comment: thank you but it produces <<< $output[] = [0=>1 , 1=>'a' , 2=>'i' , 3=>$object1]; >>> instead of <<< $output[] = ['id'=>1 , 'name'=>'a' , 'alias'=>'i' , 'object'=>$object1]; >>>

Comment: You are totally right ! I edited my post to improve the solution. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Transposing the data with `array_map()` will eliminate the need to manually count the number of iterations required.  To tidy up the preferred default values when missing, use the null coalescing assignment operator before returning the new associative row on each iteration.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QnFoo))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        function(?int $id, ?string $name, ?string $alias, ?object $object) {
            $id ??= 0;
            $name ??= '';
            $alias ??= '';
            return get_defined_vars();    
        },
        $input['id'],
        $input['name'],
        $input['alias'],
        $input['object']
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'name' => 'a',
    'alias' => 'i',
    'object' => 
    (object) array(
       'foo' => 1,
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'name' => 'b',
    'alias' => 'ii',
    'object' => 
    (object) array(
       'bar' => 2,
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 3,
    'name' => 'c',
    'alias' => 'iii',
    'object' => NULL,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => 4,
    'name' => '',
    'alias' => 'iv',
    'object' => NULL,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => 0,
    'name' => '',
    'alias' => 'v',
    'object' => NULL,
  ),
)
```